# iText7 JumpStart Tutorial Chapter 3 Handling Events ClassCastException com.itextpdf.kernel.color.DeviceRgb

Tags: itext7

Copying the iText7 JumpStart Tutorial Chapter 3 Handling Events code and running it in eclipse is generating a ClassCastException. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.itextpdf.kernel.color.DeviceRgb cannot be cast to com.itextpdf.layout.property.TransparentColor.

If I comment out the line canvas.setProperty(Property.FONT_COLOR, Color.WHITE); in that example http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/examples/chapter-3#1744-c03e03_ufo.java the PDF is created with no error. But the watermark obviously isn't applied correctly. How can I fix the ClassCastException in this example?

Comment: Something is wrong with the version of iText dependency. Make sure you are using iText 7.0.2 or 7.0.3-SNAPSHOT

Comment: I believe I am using all 7.0.2 jars for iText. I added most of the jars using a Maven build, and then for this example I added the itext7-pdftest-7.0.2.jar manually.

Comment: As Joris correctly explained in his answer, the problem turned out to be that the samples were outdated. They will be updated on the website in the nearest time, meanwhile you can always have a look at the current version of the same in the repo: https://git.itextsupport.com/projects/I7JS/repos/jumpstart/browse/src/main/java/tutorial/chapter03/C03E03_UFO.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is easily fixed, since TransparentColor has a constructor that takes an ordinary color as argument.

```
// Add watermark
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pdfDoc, page.getPageSize());
canvas.setProperty(Property.FONT_COLOR, new TransparentColor(Color.WHITE));
canvas.setProperty(Property.FONT_SIZE, 60);
canvas.setProperty(Property.FONT, helveticaBold);
canvas.showTextAligned(new Paragraph("CONFIDENTIAL"), 298, 421, pdfDoc.getPageNumber(page), TextAlignment.CENTER, VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE, 45);
```

Alternatively, you could also use

```
canvas.setFontColor(Color.WHITE);
```

I'll see about updating the examples on the iText website.
Thanks for your input!

Comment: Thank you! Both of your suggestions fixed the error. I am a Java novice and knowing when to use a constructor, implement, or extend a class can be somewhat confusing.  When I open the declaration in Eclipse for com.itextpdf.layout.property.TransparentColor I now see it has a constructor with "Color color" as an argument. I will try to explore the classes causing the error further in the future.

Comment: iText also has a very complete API that you can check out.  
http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext7/latest/